# Convert Anonymous type to IEnumerable<> in EF6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am developing an MVC application using Entity Framework. I want to get 5 columns from a table and return them in an **IEnumerable** type. My code for this is:

```
IEnumerable<MST> n = new List<MST>();
n = db.MSTs.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Code, x.Desc, x.L1, x.L2 }).OrderBy(h => h.Code).ToList();
```

But it gives me the error

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collection.Generic.List`<Anonymous#1>`' to
>   'System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable`<<MST>>`'

How can I solve it?

Comment: Are you trying to return `n`? You won't be able to return an anonymous type.

Comment: Because you creating a collection of anonymous objects, not a collection of `MST` Delete the first line of code and just use `var n = db.MSTs.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Code, x. .....`

Comment: But I am using foreach loop in the view which requires IEnumerabe type. So How can I do that"

Comment: `var n = db.MSTs.Select(..` will be `IEnumerable` but it will be an anonymous object so not much use in a view. Whats wrong with just `var n = db.MSTs.OrderBy(h => h.Code)`? Of if you need `List<MST>` instead of `IEnumerable<MST>` then add `.ToList()`

Comment: My table has 105 columns. If I get all of them its too much time consuming. So I just want to get what I need

Comment: Then create a view model and use `.Select(x => new MSTViewModel { ID = x.ID, Code = x.Code, ...})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you don't need the `ToList()` because you don't need a list:

```
db.MSTs
  .Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Code, x.Desc, x.L1, x.L2 })
  .OrderBy(h => h.Code)
```

Now you do need the type to be `MST`. If this was a type EF knew about you could include this directly in the `Select`:

```
db.MSTs
  .Select(x => new MST{ Id = x.Id, Code =x.Code, Desc = x.Desc, L1 =x.L1, L2 =x.L2 })
  .OrderBy(h => h.Code)
```

But it's not, so you need to break from EF to in-memory with `AsEnumerable` and then do the creation of `MST` after that:

```
IEnumerable<MST> n = db.MSTs
  .Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Code, x.Desc, x.L1, x.L2 }).OrderBy(h => h.Code)
  .AsEnumerable()
  .Select(x => new MST{ Id = x.Id, Code =x.Code, Desc = x.Desc, L1 =x.L1, L2 =x.L2 });
```

(If there's some reason why you really do need the `ToList()` you can use that instead of `AsEnumerable()`, but you're probably better off just placing a final `ToList()` after all of that, to get a list of the type you actually want).

If you were using asynchronous code, then we would similarly place it after the await:

```
IEnumerable<MST> n = (await db.MSTs
    .Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Code, x.Desc, x.L1, x.L2 })
    .OrderBy(h => h.Code)
    .ToListAsync())
  .Select(x => new MST{ Id = x.Id, Code =x.Code, Desc = x.Desc, L1 =x.L1, L2 =x.L2 });
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to simply project the Type `MST` instead of anonymous type:-

```
n = db.MSTs.Select(x => new MST 
                      { 
                          Id = x.Id, 
                          Code = x.Code,
                          Desc =  x.Desc, 
                          L1= x.L1, 
                          L2 = x.L2 
                       }).OrderBy(h => h.Code);
```

Provided, you have all these properties in `MST`. Also, it should not be a mapped entity it should be a DTO.

Also, you don't need `ToList` here since `Select` returns `IEnumerable<T>`.

**Update:**

Since it is a mapped entity in Entity Framework, one way is to first project the anonymous type and then the Model type like this:-

```
n = db.MSTs.Select(x => new 
                          { 
                              x.Id, 
                              x.Code,
                              x.Desc, 
                              x.L1, 
                              x.L2 
                           }).OrderBy(h => h.Code)
                           .AsEnumerable()
                           Select(x => new MST 
                                   { 
                                      Id = x.Id, 
                                      Code = x.Code,
                                      Desc =  x.Desc, 
                                      L1= x.L1, 
                                      L2 = x.L2 
                                   });
```

Comment: It is now giving the error "The entity or complex type 'Model.MST' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query."

Comment: @AwaisMahmood - Hey you cannot project it on a mapped entity. You should have a DTO instead.

Comment: So, now what can I do.. U have to return IEnumerable type with all data.. as I am using foreach loop in the view

Comment: As you said above, you don't need `ToList()`. You can use `AsEnumerable()` to bring the operation into linq-to-objects without creating a list.